# How do I add a row dynamically in KivyMD datatable?

Tags: python-3.x, kivymd

Firstly, I KNOW there are similar questions like this out there but I really could not find any answer to this as almost all answers end with a dead end.
I am familiar with python and some with Kivy and now trying KivyMD specifically for the "Material Design" part.
Okay so it looks great and works great up to the point where I want to add or remove a row dynamically from a datatable. Well I haven't even tried removing yet because of the add problem.
Using the latest and greatest 3.10.4, Python Kivy 2.1.0, and kivymd 0.104.2, I followed the KivyMD 1.0.0.dev0 documentation from where  the following code was sourced, but exits with the following error.

```
`AttributeError: 'MDDataTable' object has no attribute 'add_row'`
```

Here is the code:

```
    from kivy.metrics import dp
    
    from kivymd.app import MDApp
    from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
    from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
    from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
    from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
    
    
    class Example(MDApp):
        data_tables = None
    
        def build(self):
            layout = MDFloatLayout()  # root layout
            # Creating control buttons.
            button_box = MDBoxLayout(
                pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5},
                adaptive_size=True,
                padding="24dp",
                spacing="24dp",
            )
    
            for button_text in ["Add row", "Remove row"]:
                button_box.add_widget(
                    MDRaisedButton(
                        text=button_text, on_release=self.on_button_press
                    )
                )
    
            # Create a table.
            self.data_tables = MDDataTable(
                pos_hint={"center_y": 0.5, "center_x": 0.5},
                size_hint=(0.9, 0.6),
                use_pagination=False,
                column_data=[
                    ("No.", dp(30)),
                    ("Column 1", dp(40)),
                    ("Column 2", dp(40)),
                    ("Column 3", dp(40)),
                ],
                row_data=[("1", "1", "2", "3")],
            )
            # Adding a table and buttons to the toot layout.
            layout.add_widget(self.data_tables)
            layout.add_widget(button_box)
    
            return layout
    
        def on_button_press(self, instance_button: MDRaisedButton) -> None:
            '''Called when a control button is clicked.'''
    
            try:
                {
                    "Add row": self.add_row,
                    "Remove row": self.remove_row,
                }[instance_button.text]()
            except KeyError:
                pass
    
        def add_row(self) -> None:
            last_num_row = int(self.data_tables.row_data[-1][0])
            self.data_tables.add_row((str(last_num_row + 1), "1", "2", "3"))
    
        def remove_row(self) -> None:
            if len(self.data_tables.row_data) > 1:
                self.data_tables.remove_row(self.data_tables.row_data[-1])
    
    
    Example().run()
```

Some people suggested using self.data_tables.append witch also fails.
Please be assured that I have looked at a lot posts to this specific issue and I only found very half haerted or no answer.

Any solutions anybody?